# A Künneth Theorem for Hochschschild Homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, algebras

Assume $A$, $B$ to be $\mathbb C$-Algebras.

Is there ( under certain conditions) a Künneth theorem or a Künneth spectral sequence relating the Hochschild homology $HH(A\otimes_\mathbb C B) $ with $HH(A)$ and $HH(B)$.

Since JHF kindly answered my question I'd like to ask the follow up one:

If $B$ is a bialgebra and $A$ a $B$-module algebra via $\triangleright:B\otimes A \rightarrow A $ we can equip $B\otimes A$ with the smash product algebra structure given by

$(a\otimes b)(c\otimes d)=a(b_{(1)}\triangleright c)\otimes b_{(2)}d$

This algebra will be denoted $A\#B$. It would be rather interesting to know the relation between $HH (A\#B)$ and $HH(A)$ as well as $HH(B)$.

Comment: You can find information about the **co**homology of the crossed product by a Hopf algebra in a paper by Dragos Stefan which deals with Hopf-Galois extensions and which google should find easily.

Comment: In geneal, though, the relation is not an easy one. There are spectral sequences and so on. Notice that Ore extensions are examples of crossed products, so you can search for the several papers out there that deal with the (co)homology of Ore extensions as a guide.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're working over the field $\mathbb{C}$, the shuffle map induces an isomorphism $$HH_*(A) \otimes HH_*(B) \xrightarrow{\cong} HH_*(A \otimes B).$$ This is theorem 4.2.5 in Loday's *Cyclic homology*.

Comment: Thank you very much. See my updated question regarding smash products. Maybe you also know an answer to this case. I'd greatly appreciate it.